# How to correctly require a specific commit in Composer so that it would be available for dependent packages?

Tags: php, github, composer-php

I have a library `foo/foo-lib` which `requires` a specific commit from GitHub:

```
{
    "name": "foo/foo-lib",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "knplabs/gaufrette": "dev-master#2633721877cae79ad461f3ca06f3f77fb4fce02e"
    }
}
```

and it works fine:

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                                 
  - Updating knplabs/gaufrette dev-master (2633721 => 2633721)
    Checking out 2633721877cae79ad461f3ca06f3f77fb4fce02e

Generating autoload files
```

but when I require that library in other project:

```
{
    "name": "bar/bar-app",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "ssh://git.example.com/foo-lib"
        }
    ],
    "require-dev": {
        "foo/foo-lib": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

it yields dependency error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for foo/foo-lib dev-master -> satisfiable by foo/foo-lib[dev-master].
    - foo/foo-lib dev-master requires knplabs/gaufrette dev-master#2633721877cae79ad461f3ca06f3f77fb4fce02e -> no matching package found.
```

So my question is: how to correctly `require` the specific commit from GitHub in my library, so that it would be available in dependent packages?

Comment: Be aware that when requiring a commit, composer will not honor that commits requirements (cmoposer.json). Instead it computes the branch head requirement which will change over time. So this might work for a while, but will break for sure in the future.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You'll have to explicitly require the Gaufrette library at that hash, with a `dev` flag, in both your library and your application. Something like this should work in the application `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "bar/bar-app",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "ssh://git.example.com/foo-lib"
        }
    ],
    "require-dev": {
        "foo/foo-lib": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/gaufrette": "dev-master#2633721877cae79ad461f3ca06f3f77fb4fce02e"
    }
}
```

From [the documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links):

> If one of your dependencies has a dependency on an unstable package
>   you need to explicitly require it as well, along with its sufficient
>   stability flag.

The documentation also suggests that you'll need to include the repository for Gaufrette in your `bar/bar-app` Composer file, though it sounds like this wasn't necessary in this case. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I've already try this, doesn't work either. I think it may have something to do with Composer prefering Packagist over GitHub specifically?

Comment: Nope, I've checked with my local repositories - it's not a GitHub specific issue.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that I got this to work before. What if you add `"minimum-stability": "dev"` to the `bar/bar-app` requirements?

Comment: Adding `"minimum-stability": "dev"` got the Composer to work, but it broke all my other deps including the `Gaufrette`. It udpated everything to `dev`, and did not check out the commit I pointed out in `foo/foo-lib`.

Comment: It [looks like you're going to have to](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links) explicitly require Gaufrette at that hash in both your library, and your application. "If one of your dependencies has a dependency on an unstable package you need to explicitly require it as well, along with its sufficient stability flag." Note that you can have some packages, e.g. Gaufrette, at `dev` stability, and default to `stable` for everything else.

Comment: Yep, just came to the same conclusion and it works. Suprisingly though I did not have to include the `repositories` entry for Guafrette. Why is that since, as you pointed out, they are not resolved recursively? Could you pleas update your answer?

Comment: Looks like GitHub is supported by Composer out of the box - I've just removed the `"url": "https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette.git"` from first package and it still works.

Comment: @MaciejSz, I will, but I [don't think that GitHub is supported out of the box](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#repository). Could you clear your cache (i.e. delete `~/.composer/cache` if you're on something Unixy or something like `%APPDATA%\Composer` if you're on Windows) and try again to see if Gaufrette can be found?

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.composer/cache/ ; rm composer.lock ; rm -rf vendor/ ; composer install && cat composer.json` Outputs: `... "repositories": [], ...`. Works. Maybe it's chacking `source` from the `composer.json` on Packagist.

Comment: TL DR: "dev-master#2633721877cae79ad461f3ca06f3f77fb4fce02e"

Comment: Unfortunately, there can be situations (due to the particular branch having changed its declared requirements in later commits) that referencing a particular commit doesn't work: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6366 ... https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3705

Answer (score 30):

Here is how you do it on the command line:

```
composer update knplabs/gaufrette:dev-master#2633721 --with-dependencies
```

You don't have to use the whole hash, a hash seven characters long seems to dothe trick. As mentioned above, your project will need to support dev - which it will complain about if not already set.  Also, use `--with-dependencies` to get any dependencies of the one you are updating.

Comment: Just tried this, seems to not work with Composer 2.

Comment: ...so, how does one correlate a specific hash number to a given patch. 
In other words, how do we know what commit a patch was rolled against?

Comment: Seems to work if I use `composer require` instead of `composer update`.

Comment: worked for me with `update` on Composer version 2.1.6

Answer (score 3):

If you're making changes for a Git Repository by forking make sure that you use the 
The package name is actually defined in the package's own composer.json file - so even though I'd forked the package to my own joshuapaling github account, and the package was now residing at the URL https://github.com/joshuapaling/Cake-Resque.git, that had not influenced the package's name at all, from composers perspective.

A stupid error - but I'm new to composer, and it wasn't clear at first! So, I hope this helps someone else with the same problem.