# PHP Composer "require" OR condition with version in future

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I need to use a bugfix which has not been released yet. Can I use something like:

```
"bower-asset/yii2-pjax": "2.0.6 | dev-master#18a9183d578d81fb9dbb1c604daba48815c3ebd5 as 2.0.5"
```

or

```
"bower-asset/yii2-pjax": "2.0.6 | dev-master as 2.0.5"
```

in my `composer.json`? Where `2.0.6` is the stable version in future and `dev-master#hash` is the commit including the bugfix, now available in remote repo (@master).

Comment: Have you tried it? Can't you use `"2.0.6 | dev-master"`?

Comment: Yes, but got error "package could not be found in any version". If I am moving in the right direction, how can i configure logic like this in composer.json?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21316829/2257664), the version with hash is correct. The error message may be due to the fact that the hash does not exist in `dev master`.

Answer (score 1):

While trying to install this package, I discovered that it has a dependency (thanks to [lichunqiang](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/10959#issuecomment-188543197)).

Here is how to install the dependency and the package:

```
composer require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
composer require "bower-asset/yii2-pjax:dev-master"
```

For some reason, `composer require "bower-asset/yii2-pjax:2.0.6"` does not work, it seems that [composer-asset-plugin](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin), the Composer plugin which is used to install the Bower asset does not find any corresponding version.

---

The current version of Composer is broken, it returns this error:

> [ErrorException]
>    Illegal offset type in isset or empty

You can get back to the old version by rolling back:

```
composer self-update --rollback
```

Comment: thank you for help, i think this situation is a special case of yet another dependency conflict in software

Comment: @itnelo did you install globally `fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1`? Are composer and this package up-to-date?

Comment: I can't properly work and test this right now due to this bug in composer asset plugin: https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin/issues/191 it maybe related error and i prefer to wait until this will be fixed

Comment: already did rollback, thanks for tip. I'am ok with "bower-asset/yii2-pjax": "dev-master#18a9183d578d81fb9dbb1c604daba48815c3ebd5 as 2.0.5" right now. Was interested in solution in which I can achieve auto update to stable branch if it's become available (without manual edit composer.json)

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but I think it's a bad idea, you can't be sure that the 2.0.6 will be published or will work perfectly. You should better [manage your composer.lock through your Version Control System](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12896780/2257664).