# Commit pushed, no new release. How to update composer?

Tags: git, github, composer-php

An important update was committed to a package that my site relies on. However, no new release was made after this important commit.

How then should I update my `composer.json` in order to get the important update that I need?

Currently I have this in my `composer.json`:

```
"username/pkgname": "1.2.3"
```

I know I can change it to `dev-master`, but I have heard that this isn't an ideal change to make. Is there something else that I can do?

Comment: You'll want to require the specific hash to prevent updating to unstable versions in master. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21314381/4233593